# One object having two different colors and distortions

Tags: modeling, mesh, texturing, objects, vertices

So my question is how do I fix an object that was made by joining two separate objects together. Specifically what I want to fix is the color issue, I need it to be one color and without any distortions.(greyish black parts) Would be glad if anyone can provide feed some back.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Tab</kbd> into Edit Mode and <kbd>A</kbd> to select all then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to make the normals consistent.